# How do I access the JSON body of a PUT request to a RESTlet

Tags: restlet

If I PUT a JSON object to my restlet, eg.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email":"foo@baar"}' http://localhost:8888/api/exitems/5629499534213120
```

how do I retrieve the original JSON, ie. the `{"email":"foo@baar"}` portion within my restlet?

**UPDATE**

Here is the background to the question ...

I have a Controller class, extending ServerResource, that handles REST CRUD operations on one of my model POJOs (Person). In the update() (ie. PUT) method, I am being passed an instantiated Person object, but what I don't know is which fields were PUT by my REST client.

- If the client PUT excluded a property (say) familyName - intending this to mean 'do not update familyName', it is null in the POJO.
- On the other hand, if the client PUT a null value for familyName - intending this to mean 'set familyName to null', then the POJO familyName is also null.

How do I distinguish between these two scenarios?

Comment: Can you detail what you have on the server-side? A ServerResource subclass?

Comment: Yes. "public class ExitemController extends ServerResource implements ExitemControllerInterface"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are extending ServerResource, you can either call getRequestEntity() to retrieve the representation, or declare a Representation parameter on your @Post annotated Java method.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your updated question, it seems that you don't use the PUT method properly. The entity that you pass with your PUT request should contain the complete new state for your target resource.

In your case, it seems that you want to do only partial updates. You should rather consider using PATCH method if you really need such level of optimization.

Comment: and then how would I get the **original** JSON body. I can see getStream() and getText() as methods on Representation. Is it one of those?

Comment: Yes, you can use those (or getReader() directly) or prefer to use the JacksonRepresentation or JsonRepresentation provided in extensions for easy JSON parsing.

Comment: In my controller (which extends org.restlet.resource.ServerResource) I am trying "println(getRequestEntity().getText())" but it's returning null. If I try to get the stream with getStream(), that is also null.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't already consumed this request entity in an upstream filter for example? The content is socket bound so it can be read only once, unless you buffer it.

Comment: I'm sure I have consumed it (unless having it parsed into one of my model objects consumes it). Perhaps it would be easier if asked the "real" question instead, since it is beginning to sound like I'm going in the wrong direction. I've updated the question - hope that's OK.

Comment: I get this now, see my updated answer. If you do need to cache the entity, you can use the BuferringRepresentation wrapper entity.